# Import Tool - Error: Same Variable Names - after Column Splitting

Tags: matlab, import

I am trying to import data by using Matlab's the import tool. The data is separated by tabs. However Matlab does not separate column two and three from one another automatically, which is why I split those manually, using the ruler or right clicking and selecting "split column".

I want to import the data as a numeric matrix. If I try to click import selection --> import data the following message appears: "Two or more variable names are the same. Rename them so that they are unique.". This does not happen if I am importing as a table, cell array, or column vectors. Funny enough: in the third row, where the variable names appear if I select cell array or column vector, for numeric matrix just contains fields saying "number". This seems correct, since I do not believe that columns of a matrix need a variable name.

Pictures attached
[Before Column Splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCaXN.png)
[image: After Column Splitting and Numeric Matrix Selected]
[image: Error Message]

Can someone help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: I guess the easiest would be to not use the GUI directly, but to let the GUI output a script and manually rename the variable there.

Comment: Which variable names though? What I do not get ist why a column of a matrix would need a variable name.

Comment: Because MATLAB doesn't output matrices any more, it outputs tables. Table columns do need a name.